# Can't log in since usePAM set to no

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, permissions

I used to log in to my ec2 instance with ssh using a pem file. I modified the sshd_config parameter usePAM to no.

Now, I can't log in to the instance as usual. How could I do to enter in the server and change the param to yes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well...as all users were blocked to login the server there was no way to login. 
The solution is:

- Detach the volume of the instance.
- Attach it in to a temporary server.
- Log in to the temporal server and mount the volume.
- Once mounted, access the sshd_config file and fix it.
- Umount the volume and detache it from temporal server
- Attach it again to the initial instance.

Now instance has usePAM to yes so login is enabled again